# React Navigator 5 Stack "component" doesn't return anything

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am creating my app for my site with React Native and since I couldn't figure out how to fix the header from scrolling, I found the alternative method which is React Navigator 5.
However, in `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />`, It doesnt show anything but for iPhone, there is only text that said "Home" from the above which is the name param from the `Stack.Screen`, it should have showed the list I got from the API i called since I have tested the `FlatList` showing before React Navigation:
[image: Android and iPhone]
Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, Image, Platform, TouchableHighlight, SafeAreaView, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Main() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="Home"
                        component={Home} //Class component, Turning it to Function Component no luck for me to fix.
                    />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            postlists: [],
            postlistsnum: 0,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.SendAPI();
    }

    SendAPI() {
        //any api get command here
    }

    postRow({ item }) {
        return (
            <View
                style={PostListStyles.post}>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.postlists}
                renderItem={this.postRow}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                style={{
                    marginTop: 50,
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: add flex of one to safe area view <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>

Comment: @AshwithSaldanha It didn't work :(

Comment: I tried this in snack expo and @AshwithSaldanha was right . [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@arnabxd/joyous-cake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: 
index.js:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import Main from './Main'
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Main); //switching from App to Main
```

also thank you for the answers!

Comment: Im glad you fixed it! although i did nothing to help im sorry!

Answer (score 1):

can you try export default instead of function Main() { only...

like this: export default functionMain() {

Also i think you should not put a SafeAreaView outside a NavigationContainer.. try putting the SafeAreaView inside the Home Class